# how to use an object's parameter elsewhere in the program when it goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, multithreading

My question is as follows.

There is a parameter in an object which is in a different hierarchy in the code.
`

```
/main/a/b/c/filename.cc
The function in the file looks like the following.
bool filename::FindName(data* d)
{
const char* routname=d->Getname();
}
```

`
In this function d contains certain information which is extracted in this thread and is used and the "d" goes out of scope.

After executing multiple threads.
The control goes to a class in the following location.

```
/main/a/d/e/f/PerformCheck.cc
```

I need the information in "routname" in this class to perform a check in a function.

The burning question here is as to how I can use that information here.
I am not interested in any complex answers such as introducing a new parameter or inheritance. No threads etc.
I use makefiles etc in the project, I believe singleton pattern is also used in the code. How can it be achieved in the most simplest way?

I have tried to provide as much of a detail as I could. Any help is most welcome.

Comment: Put the string into a new `std::string`, and use it whenever you like. Can't get any simpler than that.